# Управление usb-модемом через сайт

Tags: модемы, javascript

Каким образом можно реализовать следующее:

На сайте есть номера телефонов. При нажатии на данный номер usb-модем должен совершать вызов. 
Специальное приложение Huawei модем может совершать вызовы. Может туда как-то передавать номер. Но как? 
Направьте пожалуйста.

Comment: читайте доку на свой модем, делается это через AT команды.

Comment: Управлять нужно как я понял через Hyper terminal. Тогда другой вопрос. Как через сайт посылать команды в гипер-терминал?

Comment: [man chat](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chat) если под линукс, под винду наверное тоже что-то такое есть. кажется скрипты какие-то для hyperteminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно ссылки сделать с указанием своего протокола, а в системе зарегистрировать desktop-приложение, которое этот протокол обслуживает. В ссылке указать параметры, передаваемые не устройство, а в программе реализовать передачу параметров на устройство.

Вот пример ссылки с указанием протокола skype: `<a href="skype:SkypeUser?call">SkypeUser</a>`. Взято отсюда: "[Звонок c сайта на Skype через ссылку](http://maxsof.ru/blog/2010/12/08/1/)"

Второй вариант: расширение для браузера, которое опять же вызывает desktop приложение. Но зато можно через javascript транслировать данные в обе стороны: из браузера команды в устройство, а устройства события в браузер. Такой обмен данными называется [Native.Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging)

Третий вариант: [расширение chrome.usb](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb) для браузера Chrome

Comment: Если такое приложение не существует, его придётся написать на .Net, Delphi или другом языке для desktop приложений.